# Receive a string with values and return a list

Tags: python

So, I receive a str with values, like:

```
Something="8478579"
```

And I need to get

```
Something=[8,4,7,8,5,7,9]
```

What can I do?
I tried `something.split()`,but it gives me `:something["8478579"].`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

```
>>> [int(i) for i in Something]
[8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9]
```

Or using a `map`

```
>>> Something="8478579"
>>> list(map(int, Something))
[8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to list with `list` :

```
>>> Something="8478579"
>>> list(Something)
['8', '4', '7', '8', '5', '7', '9']
```

Or if you want to convert to `int` you can use `map` :

```
>>> map(int,Something)
[8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9]
```

And if you want to use if in a loop you can just loop over your string and convert the digits to int with `int` function :

```
for i in Something :
   #do stuff with int(i)
```

Comment: i did it too but when i need to use it in a loop how can i use it?

Comment: @JoãoMiranda how you want to use in loop? can you add your code to question?>

Comment: can i do: var=map(int,something)?

Comment: @JoãoMiranda yes sure, then you'll have a list of integer within `var`

Answer (score 1):

Just map directly to integers:

```
map(int, Something)
```

On Python 3, that'll be an iterator, so you could either use `list()` on that or use a list comprehension:

```
[int(c) for c in Something]
```

Demo:

```
>>> Something="8478579"
>>> map(int, Something)
[8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9]
>>> [int(c) for c in Something]
[8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9]
```